# IAsyncresult - polling without freezing the UI?

Tags: c#, wcf, iasyncresult

I've got a windows svc which is running asynchronously (I've edited the methods and their parameters to make them async), a little like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx

However, I call the task which I want to run asynchronously (the call to the service/server), and then update the UI (using ReportProgress() on the backgroundworker - all of this is happening in the dowork() method of a backgroundworker). However, I call the Endxxx method to get the results, but the problem is, shouldn't my code look like?

```
while (!asyncresult.IsCompleted) { // Do all UI updating etc here... }

// Call endXXX here.
```

However, this approach locks the UI. At the moment, my code is like so (and doesn't lock the UI):

```
 IAsyncResult res = null;

                try
                {

                    res = serviceX.BeginXXX(ResultCallBack, "");
                }
                catch (FaultException<ManagementException> managementEx)
                {
                    Logger.Error(managementEx.Detail.ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show("Could not add printer. See log.");
                }



                    InstallBackgoundWorker.ReportProgress(90);
                    InstallBackgoundWorker.ReportProgress(91);
                    InstallBackgoundWorker.ReportProgress(93);

                    InstallBackgoundWorker.ReportProgress(94);
                    InstallBackgoundWorker.ReportProgress(95);
                    InstallBackgoundWorker.ReportProgress(96);
                    InstallBackgoundWorker.ReportProgress(97);



                    if (res.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        ResultCallBack(res);
                    }
                    InstallBackgoundWorker.ReportProgress(100);
```

Is this correct? It seems wrong to me.

Comment: FYI, this is not a Windows service, as you claimed. It's a WCF Service. A Windows Service is an application that runs on the host computer via the Service Manager, and runs regardless of whether there is a user logged in.  You had me really confused as to why you were doing this in a windows service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain that you're using the async pattern correctly.  It should look something like this:

```
void Start()
{
    System.IO.Stream s = ...;
    byte[] buf = ...;

    // start the IO.

    s.BeginRead(buf, 0, buf.Length, res =>
        {
            // this gets called when it's finished,
            // but you're in a different thread.

            int len = s.EndRead(res);

            // so you must call Dispatcher.Invoke
            // to get back to the UI thread.

            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    // perform UI updates here.
                });
        }, null);

    // the IO is started (and maybe finished) here,
    // but you probably don't need to put anything here.
}
```

Written with `Stream` because I don't know the signature of your object, but hopefully you get the idea!  You need to process the completion of the operation in the callback you give it, *not* directly after you call the Begin method.  You shouldn't need to poll the `IsCompleted` property.

Comment: So my code should call BeginXXX, and then EndXXX? I tried that, seems like the mistake I made. It executed the callback, too. So it doesn't matter how much code there is between beginxxx and endxxx?

Comment: I guess if between after the last line of ui updates and the endxxx method, if the method isn't finished, the code will wait?

Comment: You can do as many other things as you want between BeginXXX and EndXXX.

Comment: The callback is **only** called when the operation is finished.  You aren't supposed to call it -- the operation calls it for you, to notify you when it's finished.  So long as you call EndXXX in the callback, it won't need to wait.

Answer (score 0):

No you should not take the first approach, since it defeats the objective of calling a method in an async fashion.

Second approach is also troublesome since

- your progress reporting is arbitrary and unrealistic
- even with 100% it does not guarantee that the work is done since at 100% it does not know if the work has been done.

There is no way to show a progress report for an async job unless async just provides it.

Solution is:

- Show an **indeterminate** progress bar (also called spinner)
- Report user of the result **inside the callback**

You must also be aware of the issues communicating with the UI thread from a background thread and using Invoke in Windows Forms and using Dispatcher in WPF.

Comment: Exactly what I thought. So what's the best way to do this without locking the UI?

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the issues like using Conrol.Invoke. How do I show an indeterminate progress bar? When I make the call to EndXXX, how would I do so only when the IsCompleted = true?

Comment: Well, I know in WPF you can set Progressbar.IsIndeterminate to true. Not sure about windows forms.

Comment: I can use a marquee to achieve that (in progress-bar). The second question remains, however?